# Keras CategoricalCrossentropy along axis

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I am trying to implement a categorical crossentropy (CCE) loss that returns a tensor of a given shape and not a single number.

I have two tensors, lets call them `a` and `b` of shape [`batch_size, 5, 5, 10]`. When I feed them to the categorical crossentropy from keras, I always obtain a single value, which is not what I want.

I want a tensor of values of the shape `[batch_size, 5, 5, 1]`, so I want to apply CCE only to the last dimension.

I tried to play around with the axis parameter but this only changes across which axis CCE sums and has no impact on the output dimension.
When I use the ellipsis operator I still only obtain one value as in

```
bce = tf.keras.CategoricalCrossentropy()
temp = bce(a[...,0:], b[...,0:])
```

which returns me:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=-5.292599360151803>
```

What can I do to get my desired output?

Comment: Look into the `reduction` argument of the call: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy . Otherwise, pull the source of `CategoricalCrossentropy` and rewrite it to suit your needs.

Comment: @KDecker, thanks the reduction argument was exactly what I needed